# Keep selected data after form submit

Tags: javascript

I have this form here:

```
<form action="listasearch.php" method="get">
<select name="kategoria">
  <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
  <option value="id">ID</option>
  <option value="dyqani_pergjegjes">Dyqani Përgjegjës</option>
  <option value="emri">Emri</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

The issue is, i need to keep the selected value, I would do it if i had two similar names, i.e
dyqani_pergjegjes and dyqani_pergjegjes, but it's Dyqani Pergjegjes then.

Someone please could help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: If you just eliminate the `value` attribute, the option will take the value of the text within the `<option></option>` tags.

Comment: Yes. nut i don't need that to happen...

Comment: do you mean you want to keep the selected value when the form loads next time?

Comment: What does the two similar names have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean...

Comment: "Dyqani Pergjegjes"  is from database?

Comment: dyqani_pergjegjes is in the database, but a user should see it Dyqani Pergjegjes in the select text...

Comment: and when you are saving the selected value to display it after the page refresh, you are saving "Dyqani Pergjegjes" and not "dyqani_pergjegjes", right?

Comment: Exact rps :) that's what i need

Comment: Post your code where you are saving the selected value ("Dyqani Pergjegjes") for later use

Comment: The idea is this, in each page i have this form, it's the search form i use everywhere, i get my selected values, query , get results, but if i.e in test.php page i've selected the ID, when i submit the form, in the other page listasearch.php is the same form, i need ID to be selected, so the user knows what has selected, not to be reset

Comment: yes, I get it, If it is selected in one page then it has to appear selected in other page too. now, you have saved the "Dyqani Pergjegjes" value in test.php right? and you are able to see that same "Dyqani Pergjegjes" in listasearch.php too right?

Comment: Yes, yes, that's right

Comment: now what you have to do is save "dyqani_pergjegjes" instead of "Dyqani Pergjegjes" in the test.php, so, if you post your code that you use to save "Dyqani Pergjegjes" in test.php it will be helpful.

Comment: Is there any option, for javascript , because in listasearch.php i get the kategoria value, and the select dropdown to bring in first the value that corresponds to what i have saved

Comment: I don't know php, but in your case is it possible to get "Dyqani Pergjegjes" inside a script?

Comment: this isn't php i really need, let's put it this way, in listasearch, i have a value $kategoria and i need to get from teh form, on top the option that corresponds to this value, i suppose it's doable

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/cDmxd/](http://jsfiddle.net/cDmxd/) Like this?

Comment: Ah great great :), but is it possible in spite of Dyqani Pergjegjes to put dyqani_pergjegjes?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/cDmxd/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cDmxd/1/) Like this :) ?

Comment: perfect, now, last thing, how can i insert a php value instead of that? because the phph value contains the dyqani_pergjegjes value :)

Comment: :D... see this is why I said before that I don't know php, Let us ask @DevlshOne ! by the way you  will have to add that code in body onload function okay.

Comment: Yes, i found out how to load it :)
please post it as an answer so i can accept :)
thank you so so much

Comment: ah good to know. anytime... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var select=document.getElementsByName("kategoria");
for(var i=0;i<select[0].options.length;i++){    
  if(select[0].options[i].text=="Dyqani Përgjegjës")
 // if(select[0].options[i].value=="dyqani_pergjegjes")  //or
  select[0].selectedIndex=i;
}
```

Comment: Great, see, i added this :    var kategoria = '<?php echo $kategoria; ?>';
, how can i make  if(select[0].options[i].text==var kategoria)?

Comment: `if(select[0].options[i].text==kategoria)` if kategoria=""Dyqani Përgjegjës""